# Can this rough design show the required message?

Tags: typography, design-principles, graphic-styles, advertising

Please see this image:

[image]

To show a revoked/scrapped Article say 370 on social media, I'm thinking to make something like this. (7 with torn paper). Also, I'll write a related copy as well below it.

Does it make sense (I mean can it be recognized, the paper as an article and number 7)?

Comment: Perhaps it’s just the drawing, but I immediately read it as “three kitchen mixer zero” and was none the wiser. It didn’t occur to me that the drawing was supposed to represent a number seven. Most of all, though, this idea falls flat on its face, if I understand you correctly, if the revoked or scrapped article doesn’t have a number seven in it. What if it’s article 22?

Comment: Technique: <sarcasm>There's nothing like a leading question to get an honest unbiased answer. </sarcasm> Instead of asking if something looks like (insert suggestion you want to hear), why not show the "thing" and ask what it appears to be? If noooobody can correctly "read" your design, go back to the drawing board and play some more. Vikas, You don't have the benefit of explaining your design to the target audience. Your design should be clear enough on its own to do all the explaining necessary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I shared it on Looking Glass group for feedback, if you want to see the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a good use of [negative space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space) to convey your message. Things to look out for:

- make sure the "7" shape doesn't look like it's a different font from the other numbers.
- keep it simple, try to not add too much detail to the torn paper that could obscure the shape of the "7".
- ensure there's good contrast between the empty shape and background so you can see the number
- depending on the size of the final image you might want to use a bolder font

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, negative space shape of 7 would be like a torn paper (not smooth edges). Do you think the shape of 3 and 7 should also be uneven and not smooth, just like torn paper edges?

Comment: @Vikas It could be, if it doesn't make the image too busy, but I don't think it's necessary. Try to keep details to a minimum or it can be too distracting. You could try to make all the numbers were in the torn paper, so all numbers would be negative space, if it's not too messy.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14XxABb5jgzIxvJYAMJGEEXrxYPLkbEsb what do you think?

Comment: It's not broken 370, it's a 3, two pieces of paper and a 0. The papers can be also seen as 2 boxes.

Answer (score 3):

there's still good 3 and 0 and something splintered between them. If you want to break 370, break it as a whole.

[image]

Comment: Yeah :D but its too common. I won't learn much from it.

Comment: The other possibility is to present some consequence of the scrapping. I cannot tell which is a proper thing where you live. I guess that a proper selection is essential to keep oneself out of the way of knives and bullets.

Comment: I've shared it on Looking Glass. Would you please share your valuable feedback?